# How to set up an external IP address

Tags: networking, 16.04, ip

EDIT: this is for outside of network access.

I'm configuring remote desktop access to my Ubuntu following [this tutorial](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9962). However, after testing the connection, it doesn't work.
I imagine it's because I never setup an external IP for my Ubuntu machine. :)

I don't have experience in this area, so I was looking to [this article](https://whstatic.1and1.com/help/CloudServer/EN-US/d851242.html) on how to setup an external IP address.
But before I go ahead, a couple of questions. Is an external IP address, what I should be looking for? And do I need to have any security concerns by creating one?

Comment: do you want to access your ubuntu computer from outside of your network? then you would have to set portforwarding in your router.

Comment: Yes, I need to access outside my home network. So do I just need to setup port forwarding? No need for external IP?

Comment: well, you will need to set portforwarding in your router to your ubuntu computer for port 5900 (if you use the default port). then the issue with the ip. you always have an external ip address when you are on the internet. you just have to know it. you can either look up your ip address every time, or you use a dynamic dns service (which you have to set up for example in your router as well). then you would have a domain, which always will resolve to your network. google for "free dynamic dns" ;)